# Laravel npm run build problems

Tags: laravel, npm, nvm

I'm trying to deploy laravel 10 project on hosting. Project with laravel breeze and some problems while npm run.
Server uses nvm 0.39.3 and npm 9.6.5, gallium v16.20.0

`npm run dev` returns

```
LARAVEL v10.8.0  plugin v0.7.4

  ➜  APP_URL: http://xxxx.xxx
Error:   Failed to scan for dependencies from entries:
  /home/c/cn18045/public_html/resources/js/app.js
```

`npm run build`
returns

`failed to load config from /home/c/cn18045/public_html/vite.config.js`

Comment: Okay, well... does `/home/c/cn18045/public_html/vite.config.js` exist?

Comment: yeah, it contents
```import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});```

Comment: Your app should not be in public_html folder, it should be in client inaccessible folder with public folder of app symlinked to public_html. I am not sure if that will solve the issue but vite.config.js is not a public folder and nor is resources. The index.php file inside public folder is the one that loads laravel, so I am not sure if your app is running at all with that setup

Comment: @AdemirŠehić app is runnning. Other urls (not breeze) is working well

Comment: Where did you call `npm run build`? In `/home/c/cn18045` or `/home/c/cn18045/public_html`?

Comment: @Charlie in `public_html`

Comment: @ichwillkin There is not much info can tell what could be the issue, suggest 1. Check your vite.config.js exists on hosting 2. Check your permissions setting, on Linux at least 644.